# Ionic Dañado? Despues de la actualizacion

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript, angular

Desde la última actualización de Ionic, se muestra en consola este error, ¿qué me recomiendan hacer?.
Antes tenia ionic 3, pero actualize y me salieron todos esos errores, ahora tnego la 3.20.0, y la actualizacion me pedia actualizar unos paquetes de Angular Cli @angular.. etc uso npm para actualizar.

```
Error
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
.../xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts
import { Type } from './type';
import { NgZone } from './zone/ng_zone';
export declare const ALLOW_MULTIPLE_PLATFORMS: InjectionToken<boolean>;
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/core/src/event_emitter.d.ts
* In the following example, `Zippy` alternatively emits `open` and `close` events when its
* title gets clicked:
*
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...ampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/query_list.d.ts
* provide.
*
* Implements an iterable interface, therefore it can be used in both ES6
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.d.ts
 * Determine if the argument is an Observable
 */
export declare function isObservable(obj: any | Observable<any>): obj is Observable<any>;
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...bando/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives/abstract_control_directive.d.ts
* Only used internally in the forms module.
*
* @stable
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives/validators.d.ts
/**
 * An interface that can be implemented by classes that can act as validators.
 *
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/model.d.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AsyncValidatorFn, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from './directives/validators';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/validators.d.ts
* Provide this using `multi: true` to add validators.
*
* ### Example
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.d.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReadyState } from '../enums';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
...p/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.d.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ResponseOptions } from '../base_response_options';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { RequestOptions } from './base_request_options';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators.d.ts
import 'rxjs/observable/throw';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export interface PluginConfig {
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/plugin.d.ts
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CordovaOptions } from './decorators';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
...mpp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/input/input.d.ts
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
Typescript Error
Module '"C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'.
...xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/tabs/tabs.d.ts
import { AfterViewInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Renderer, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
Typescript Error
Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts
export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observable';
Typescript Error
Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Subject'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts
export * from 'rxjs-compat/Subject';
Typescript Error
Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/observable/throw'.
C:/xampp/htdocs/ionic/probando/node_modules/rxjs/observable/throw.d.ts
export * from 'rxjs-compat/observable/throw';
```

Comment: Necesito que especifiques más a cerca del error producido: - ¿qué ionic tenías antes?: de Ionic 1 a Ionic 2+ puede darte problemas - ¿qué proceso has usado para la actualización?: Has usado el CLI, npm,...etc

Comment: Antes tenia ionic 3, pero actualize y me salieron todos esos errores, ahora tnego la 3.20.0, y la actualizacion me pedia actualizar unos paquetes de Angular Cli @angular.. etc uso npm para actualizar.

Comment: ¿borraste antes de la actualización la carpeta node_modules?,después  ¿actualizaste el package.json y a continuación introducir en consola   npm install?

Comment: Solucionado aplique npm install y se soluciono.